# LSTM TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method,

Tags: python, lstm

I already build the LSTM model , but i still cannot see the feature importance of the y variable. I could the error like the following, allow i have tried to change the enviroment.
could anyone help me? Thanks in advance.

```
import os
os.environ["SM_FRAMEWORK"] = "tf.keras"

lstm_classifier = LSTMClassifier(Cluster_0)

lstm_classifier.preprocess_data()

X_test = lstm_classifier.get_X_test()
y_test = lstm_classifier.get_y_test()

feature_importances = lstm_classifier.get_feature_importance(X_test, y_test)

---------------------------------------------------------------------------
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
TypeError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-61-046c9c5bbede> in <cell line: 12>()
     10 
     11 
---> 12 feature_importances = lstm_classifier.get_feature_importance(X_test, y_test)

2 frames
<ipython-input-57-8bc9dce06edb> in get_feature_importance(self, X, y, n_repeats, random_state)
    150 
    151         # Compute the permutation importance
--> 152         result = permutation_importance(predict_proba_wrapped, X, y, n_repeats=n_repeats,
    153                                         random_state=random_state, n_jobs=-1)
    154 

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/inspection/_permutation_importance.py in permutation_importance(estimator, X, y, scoring, n_repeats, n_jobs, random_state, sample_weight, max_samples)
    249         scorer = scoring
    250     elif scoring is None or isinstance(scoring, str):
--> 251         scorer = check_scoring(estimator, scoring=scoring)
    252     else:
    253         scorers_dict = _check_multimetric_scoring(estimator, scoring)

/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sklearn/metrics/_scorer.py in check_scoring(estimator, scoring, allow_none)
    472     """
    473     if not hasattr(estimator, "fit"):
--> 474         raise TypeError(
    475             "estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, %r was passed"
    476             % estimator

TypeError: estimator should be an estimator implementing 'fit' method, <function LSTMClassifier.get_feature_importance.<locals>.predict_proba_wrapped at 0x79fb6f5d7eb0> was passed
```

Answer (score 0):

So it seems like you are using a class that is an estimator. There is not much code to go on and the question is vaguely worded but I am going to use an sklearn estimator as an example.

Certain funcionality that works on estimators require an estimator class that has specific functions. The error asks for a fit function so you might not have implemented it.

Scikit-learn has estimator functions described like this.

https://scikit-learn.org/stable/developers/develop.html

Just like you are calling feature_importance it might require you to make a function as part of the estimator called fit

```py
class estimator:
    def get_feature_importance():
        return
    def fit(self,x,y):
       do something
```